# Reading materials for scalability analysis?

Tags: scalability

I'm looking for educational material on the subject of scalability analysis. I'm not simply looking for Big-O analysis, but for material on approaches and techniques for analysis of the scalability of large scale transactional systems. Amazon's orders and payment systems might be good examples of the sort of systems I'm referring to.

I have a preference for online materials, including text and video, in that they tend to be easily accessible but I'm open to book suggestions, too.

Comment: I would tag this "scalability-analysis" if only SO would let me create a tag... :)

Comment: Thanks! Still hoping to see a few more answers.

Comment: This is a better fit for the "scalability" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[highscalability blog](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhighscalability.com%2F&ei=A0GdSsjuC8_DsgaCyJ2yAQ&usg=AFQjCNEhcR3dd0uA80jrZopYVUwFkrFA2Q&sig2=pSz-cwTYHp1bf9WMgCVeTg), for real life issues